# Horizontal gap between floated tables in Outlook 2007/2010

Tags: html-table, css-float, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I've spent two weeks to find any solution for this, but can't came across. If you float tables after each, there will be a one pixel gap in Microsoft Outlook 2007/2010, which uses the Microsoft Word 2007 HTML render engine:

[image]

I'd thank you any working solution – *which is not to put the tables in separated `<td>`'s*.

**Here is the HTML code for reproduce it:**

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Outlook 2007/2010 horizontal gap</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        table { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <table bgcolor="#ffff00" align="left"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
    <table bgcolor="#ffff00" align="left"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- `display: inline-table;` instead of `align="left"`
- searched for other relevant `mso-` CSS attributes with no luck
- removed whitespaces between `<table>` elements
- `border-collapse: collapse` and `border-spacing: 0`
- adding `border: 1px solid red;` will remove gap but increase the width of the tables
- other `display`'s, `padding` and `margin`
- non related or deprecated html attributes (`rules`, `frame`, `border`, etc.) on `<td>` and/or `<table>`

---

**Fun factor:**

If you put these two tables into a table, the extra gap's width will increase to 2 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to float tables. You need a combination of border="1" and mso-table css in there to get rid of the 1px gap. See example:

```
<table bgcolor="#454545" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td width="5%"></td><td align="center" width="95%">


<div align="left" style="float: left; padding: 0px; margin:0px;">
  <table border="1" bordercolor="#959595" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin:0px; mso-table-lspace: -1pt; mso-table-rspace: -1pt; ">
    <tr>
      <td width="318" bgcolor="959595">table 1

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div align="left" style="float: left; padding: 0px; margin:0px;">
  <table border="1" bordercolor="#959595" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="padding: 0px; margin:0px; mso-table-lspace:-1pt; mso-table-rspace: -1pt; ">
    <tr>
      <td width="318" bgcolor="959595">table 2

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" on each of the two table's. If i understand your issue correct this should solve it :)

Comment: No, this will not help with the issue. The gap is between the table's border, even these values are 0.

Answer (score 0):

We might be SOL here. I am also working on email formats compatible with Outlook 2007/10. If my readings are correct, Outlook 2007/10/13 do not support `border-spacing` for tables, which is probably what's giving you that spacing issue.

Refs:
[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_Full)
[Guide to CSS support in email | Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)